# Can I pass two arguments to a Worklight adapter onSuccess function?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I am unable to pass two arguments to the adapter onSuccess() function using IBM Worklight. Please show me the way. Here is what I am currently trying:

```
var options = {
    onSuccess : SubCategoriesSuccess(options, result),
    onFailure : SubCategoriesFailure,
    invocationContext: {}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onSuccess` parameter requires a *reference* to a function, not an invocation of a function - note that there is a difference between `SubCategoriesSuccess` and `SubCategoriesSuccess()` in JavaScript. What you are doing is passing the result of calling `SubCategoriesSuccess(options, result)`.

What you need is what is typically referred to as *partial invocation* in programming jargon. JavaScript itself has a function for doing this - [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). You should probably look at that (although there alternatives provided by various JavaScript toolkits too).

This would mean your code would look something like:

```
{
  onSuccess : SubCategoriesSuccess.bind(this, options, result),
  onFailure : SubCategoriesFailure,
  invocationContext: {}
};
```

Note that I have *not* tested this.

Answer (score 0):

If options is a variable already on your calling function.  You have to wrap the return function in another.  So in other words, success is returned from the adapter, and options is just passed along by the calling function.

```
 onSuccess:function(result){
    SubCategoriesSuccess(options, result);
 }
```